# Android: Tabs and searchbars

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-lifecycle, android-search

I have two tabs and each tabs has its own searchbar.

I bind the searchbar in `onCreateOptionsMenu`. However, the searchbars only work if I leave the screen once and return to the screen (meaning it needs one more lifecycle for the searchbars to react). I confirmed that onCreateOptionsMenu is indeed called two times at the time of the creation of the ViewPagerFragment.

I bind them like this:

```java
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
searchItem.setVisible(true);

SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
   @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
          ...
          return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
           ...
          return false;
     }
});
```

I am guessing this bug is related to the tabs. How do implement a working searchbar with tabs (i.e. viewpager2)?

---

I call this on onCreateOptionsMenu:

```java
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    // Call the above...
}
```

The ViewPager hosting them looks like this:

```java
private void init(View view) {
    ViewPager2 viewPager2 = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_fragment_view_pager);
    TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_fragment_view_pager);
    viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(true);

    viewPager2.setAdapter(new ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(ViewPagerFragment.this));
    viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);

    new TabLayoutMediator
            (tabLayout, viewPager2,
                    (tab, position) -> tab.setText(titles[position])).attach();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your issue come from your `searchView` have you done some research in this way ?

Comment: It seems the issue is related to both the fragments calling (creating) the menu. In this case, you should use the activity to inflate the menu and bind the search bar and based on the current page (fragment), dispatch the events to that fragment.

Comment: I do not think I can do that, I am calling all previous method in onCreateOptionsMenu  in each Fragment - see my updated question.

Comment: @Froyo I added more information in my post.

Comment: Maybe you should move this part of code to onPrepareOptionsMenu method and call activity's invalidateOptionsMenu() method when viewPager page changes?

Comment: @BakhtiyorBegmatov That doesnt change it either. I still need to switch to the other fragment and back for it work. I think the binding that I do in onCreateOptionsMenu or onPrepareOptionsMenu gets somehow overriden (maybe by the hosting fragment) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP and I were communicating while we found a solution.

First each fragment was changed to

```
public class MergedItemsFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    /// ------------------------------
    /// SearchView.OnQueryTextListener

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // ...
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // ...
        return false;

    }

    /// --------
    /// Fragment

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_merged_items, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        final MenuItem   searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    }

}
```

- `SearchView` was inflated by using a menu.xml file within the App's Activity.
- `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` was implemented by each `Fragment` that needed access to the `SearchView`
- Since `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is invoked each time a `Fragment` is created, or subsequently comes into view (e.g. Swipe); the `SearchView`'s `OnQueryTextListener` is updated to the corresponding `Fragment`
- Lastly, there was a line in OP's main `Fragment` containing the `ViewPager2`, which was removed: `viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);` that caused each `Fragment` provided by the `FragmentStateAdapter` to instantiate and mutate the `SearchView`'s `OnQueryTextListener` each time a `Fragment` was created. 
  Removing the line made sure that only the `Fragment` that was in view was bound to the `Toolbar`'s `SearchView`.

If any more code is desired, i'd be happy to post what I have, and if I come up with a solution using `viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);` i.e. caching, i'll post that as well